# SMS Error: "Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DateAdd Parameter Name: InputDate..."

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

I'm sending 2 very similar SMSs on a journey and one of them is not working properly. When I preview it, it gives me this error:

> Invalid value specified for function parameter.
> Function Name: DateAdd
> Parameter Name: InputDate
> Parameter Ordinal: 1
> Parameter Type: Date
> Submitted Value:
> ClientID: 110008019
> JobID: 0
> ListID: 0
> BatchID: 0
> SubcriberID: 0
> Data Source Type: CustomObject
> Data Source ID: 07e90d92-24f9-eb11-a304-48df37342d01

Since they are so similar, I don't know what could be causing the issue. Here are the codes for them:

SMS #1 (working fine):

```
    %%[ 
    VAR @hoje, @datalimite 
    SET @hoje = Now() 
    SET @datalimite = DateAdd(@hoje, 12, "D")
    
    InsertData("DE_TESTE_2WAY_AUM_LIMITE",DIA_ENTRADA,@hoje)
    
    ]%%

    **Other displayed text** Condicoes validas ate %%=Format(@datalimite, "dd/MM")=%%.
```

SMS #2 (not working correctly):

```
    %%[ 
    VAR @dataentrada, @datalimite
    SET @dataentrada = Lookup("DE_TESTE_2WAY_AUM_LIMITE","DIA_ENTRADA","CELULAR",MOBILE_NUMBER)
    SET @datalimite = DateAdd(@dataentrada, 8, "D")
    
    ]%%

    **Other displayed text** Condicoes validas ate %%=Format(@datalimite, "dd/MM")=%%.
```

I tried removing the `DateAdd` function and it works. I also tried displaying the `@dataentrada` field and it also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMpscript function `DateAdd` throws the error in the second SMS because it cannot work with an empty value coming from the `@dataentrada` variable. In other words, your `Lookup` function results in an empty value and that is the problem here.

That is why your first SMS is working as expected, since the `@hoje` variable cannot be empty, it is always is set to reflect the current timestamp.

To cover this scenario, it would be recommended to check if `Lookup` brings any value and then if not - set either static fallback value for `@datalimite`, another way how to set this variable or change the output text to show error -

```
%%[

VAR @dataentrada, @datalimite, @Output_Text
SET @dataentrada = Lookup("DE_TESTE_2WAY_AUM_LIMITE", "DIA_ENTRADA", "CELULAR", MOBILE_NUMBER)

IF NOT EMPTY(@dataentrada) THEN
    SET @datalimite = DateAdd(@dataentrada, 8, "D")
    SET @Output_Text = Concat("Condicoes validas ate ", Format(@datalimite, "dd/MM"), ".")
ELSE
    SET @Output_Text = "No valid date is found."
ENDIF

]%%

**Other displayed text**
%%=v(@Output_Text)=%%
```

It is also easier to troubleshoot AMpscript in emails since you can preview the email without even any content and see how AMPscript would be processed.

Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Hey, Niko!

Thanks for your reply! I tried to display the @datalimite value and it displayed correctly, the value that is written on the DE. The first thing on the journey is an "update contact" that fills this field "DIA_ENTRADA", so technically it shouldn't be empty ever.

Anyway, I'll try this and get back here if it works or not. And thank you for the tip on doing it in emails :)

Comment: Hello, can you attach an example of the value you are pulling by this `Lookup` function, please? Yeah, I understood the flow but something is still incorrect with `@datalimite` since that is what the error is telling us.

Comment: Hey, Niko! I just tried what you suggested and it worked as "bypassing" the error, but the message displayed is as it's an empty value.

The value that I'm pulling is a DATE field and it's value is: "8/9/2021 2:32:40 PM"

Comment: Ok, I have tried to hardcode your value and the format is fine. Since it bypassed the error and went to the `ELSE` path, then it definitely means that your `Lookup` function results in an empty value for some reason. Just to confirm, have you tried outputting this - `%%=v(@dataentrada)=%%`, not `@datalimite` as you mentioned before?

Comment: I removed the `DateAdd` and tried `%%=v(@dataentrada)=%%` and it shows me nothing, even though I can see on the left side of the preview, where the information from the data extension is, that the field is filled correctly.

Comment: Basically, this:

`%%[ 
    VAR @dataentrada, @datalimite
    SET @dataentrada = Lookup("DE_TESTE_2WAY_AUM_LIMITE","DIA_ENTRADA","CELULAR",MOBILE_NUMBER)
    
    ]%%

Hello, %%=v(@dataentrada)=%%!`

Shows me this:

Hello, !

Comment: btw, `MOBILE_NUMBER` in the email would **not** be populated because this is [MobileConnect Data String](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/). So to test it in the email you would need to pick some value from the DE and hardcode it in the AMPscript.

Comment: I'm testing on the subscriber preview from Journey Builder's SMS editor. Can this be the problem?

Comment: No, you cannot use that in preview still unfortunately, this `MOBILE_NUMBER` is populated only in send context. This still does not change the main issue that your Lookup `@dataentrada` variable is empty.

Comment: Hey, Niko! I had to put a 10 minute wait in order to guarantee that the field was populated and it worked! Thank you so much for your attention and dedication :)